# jquery 1.7 .on not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a weird problem with jquery's .on , 
I have this code to add new row to a table:

```
$('#converastions_list tr:first').after(append_html);
```

One of the things that it addes is a button:

```
<input id="chat_98" class="answerChat  btn" value="answer" conversation-id="98" rep-email="xxx" type="button">
```

And i'm trying to detect a click on this button with:3

```
$(".answerChat").on("click",function() {
    alert("clicked");  
});
```

This works fine with the buttons that loaded trough PHP, but not working with buttons that i added trough JS.

I'm using jquery 1.7. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just update to jquery 1.10.2? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use a delegate for element with class .answerChat

$(document).on("click",".answerChat",function() {
    alert("see if clicked");  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `event Deligation` method with `.on()` like

```
$('#converastions_list tr:first').on("click", ".answerChat", function() {
    alert("clicked");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you are not using event delegation format of `.on()`.

The event should be bound to an element which is already present in the dom when the script is executed and the target element's selector must be passes as the second parameter.

```
$('#converastions_list tr:first').on("click", ".answerChat", function() {
    alert("clicked");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **dynamically created elements**,

```
$(document).on("click",".answerChat",function() {
    alert("clicked");  
});
```

Or write `click event` after `appending html` like,

```
$('#converastions_list tr:first').after(append_html);
$(".answerChat").on("click",function() {// add after appending anserChat element
    alert("clicked");  
});
```